# Libgdx: FitViewPort not working

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, viewport

I got image of super mario level1 (1563x224): [image: super mario level1]
But when you play the game you are not seeing all the level. 
These are my values:

```
// level1.png image size: 1563x224
// viewPort size: 300x224
public static final float LEVEL1_WIDTH = 1563f;
public static final float LEVEL1_HEIGHT = 224f;

public static final float VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 300f;
public static final float VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 224f;
```

This is part of my game constructor:

```
    _gamecam = new OrthographicCamera(ZombieGame.LEVEL1_WIDTH, ZombieGame.LEVEL1_HEIGHT); // set the world size
    _viewport = new FitViewport(ZombieGame.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, ZombieGame.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT, _gamecam); // set the viewport size
    _gamecam.position.set(ZombieGame.VIEWPORT_WIDTH / 2f, ZombieGame.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT / 2f, 0); // set the camera to be in the middle of the viewport
    _background = new Texture("level1.png"); // load level1 (background) image
```

This is my render method:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    _gamecam.update();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,1,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    _game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(_gamecam.combined);
    _game.batch.begin();
    _game.batch.draw(_background, 0, 0, ZombieGame.LEVEL1_WIDTH, ZombieGame.LEVEL1_HEIGHT);
    _game.batch.end();
}
```

For some reason it seemed it's only working in these rations, when I try to change my `VIEWPORT_HEIGHT` or `VIEWPORT_WIDTH` it's shows out of my image:

view port size: `300x224` (working):
[image: 300x224 image working]

view port size: `300x100` (not working):
[image: 300x100 image not working]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FitViewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#fitviewport) always maintain the aspect ratio of the virtual screen size (virtual viewport), while scaling it as much as possible to fit the screen.

Pass `viewportWidth` and `viewportHeight` in constructor of `OrthographicCamera` not your `.tmx` total dimension.

```
_gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
_gamecam.setToOrtho(false,ZombieGame.VIEWPORT_WIDTH,ZombieGame.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
_viewport = new FitViewport(ZombieGame.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, ZombieGame.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT, _gamecam);
```

We use viewport because it manages a Camera's viewportWidth and viewportHeight according to our [ViewPort](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) choice.

Calculate the viewport parameters and update the camera whenever resize event occurs.

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    _viewport.update(width,height,true); 
}
```

Comment: So how dose libgdx knows what is the size of my world?

Comment: what do you mean by world size ?

Comment: `LEVEL1_WIDTH` and `LEVEL1_HEIGHT` i'm not passing it nowhere.

Comment: In side platformer game `LEVEL1_HEIGHT` should be same as your `Viewport height`. you can move your camera in x direction up to   `LEVEL1_WIDTH`, you've to manage by yourself that you reached final ending point

Comment: The setToOrtho call on the camera is redundant. The Viewport handles that for you when you update it.